# Objective C iPad Animation with large images - What method to use?

Tags: objective-c, core-animation, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to build a weather application on the iPad but it seems that I need some help in animation. Say I'm animating a Radar, so the radar source files have 10 gif/jpeg pictures in 900x700 pixel size. I've tried the UIImage animation technique using the tutorial here:

http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/07/24/iphone-programming-tutorial-animating-a-game-sprite/

but it seems that loading 10 images that big is too much for the iPad to handle and its crashing due to memory warnings. I'm researching other techniques to animate but I can't seem to find something that will do this efficiently.

I've looked at others like Core Animation using sprites, and Cocos2D with sprites. Can someone point in the right direction the best way to animate these big images? (keep in mind that these images are dynamic and changes often so the sprites will have to be recreated on a server and fetched from the iPad to do the animation). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL only creates textures with dimensions at powers of 2. In the case of your images, that's 1024x1024, which is a meg of memory per image. Still, that shouldn't be a problem with the iPad.

First, investigate using Xcode's profiling tools to ensure the images aren't being repeatedly loaded into memory at each loop of the animation (likely by way of new objects that aren't sharing cached textures). That could solve your problem from the start.

Second, I recommend using Cocos2D if only for the easy handling of textures and caching. Toss the images into a CCAnimation, pop that into a CCRepeatForever, run it with a CCSequence. When you're done hit CCTextureCache to release unused textures.

Third, lower your animation framerate to 30 or less (if only for this animation). It may be the iPad, but you making a weather app. Not a video game.

Finally, downgrade the size of your image. Justify all you want, but a large radar animation will not sell your app. And just because a website might already be playing that animation beautifully, remember that a desktop has vastly more memory and power than any smart phone.

Answer (score 1):

Try breaking the animation image into into smaller parts and animate those instead by treating each components as sprites. It would be best if you use primarily code (CoreGraphics) and draw your radar "by hand" instead of just using images as if they were animated GIFs.